# Less margin-top/top

Tags: html, css

I'm developing a website for a company right now. I've done a table and now they say that the td must be also a link. The problem is that one td has three lines and the three lines must be the same link tag. I used a paragraph tag inside the link to change the line height, because they want the three lines with less line space, but it leaves a top space that must be removed. I've tried changing the margin-top, padding-top, td height... Nothing seems to work. If someone can help me I'll appreciate it.

Thank you.

Here's my code:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>COMUNITAT</th>
    <td><a href="#">Bé comú</a></td>
    <td><a href="#">Glocalitat</a></td>
    <td><a href="#">Cercle</a></td>
    <td><a href="#">Lideratge</a></td>
    <td><a href="#">Comunicació</a></td>
    <td><a href="#">Famílies</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>EDUACIÓ</th>
    <td><a href="#">Aprenentatge</a></td>
    <td><a href="#">Qualitat</a></td>
    <td><a href="#">Idiomes</a></td>
    <td><a href="#">Personalització</a></td>
    <td><a href="#">Llenguatges</a></td>
    <td><a href="#">Creativitat</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>CARÀCTER</th>
    <td><a href="#">Identitat</a></td>
    <td><a href="#">Espiritualitat</a></td>
    <td><a href="#">Fet religiós</a></td>
    <td><a href="#">Equitat</a></td>
    <td><a href="#">Passió</a></td>
    <td><a href="#">Rol educador</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr style='border:none !important; vertical-align: top;'>
    <th>ENTORN</th>
    <td>
      <a href="#">
        <p>Escola<br/>Universitat<br/>Empresa</p>
      </a>
    </td>
    <td><a href="#">Oberts</a></td>
    <td><a href="#">Tecnologia</a></td>
    <td><a href="#">Arquitectura</a></td>
    <td><a href="#">Oferta</a></td>
    <td><a href="#">Transformadors</a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

And here's my actual CSS:

```css
table a p {
    font-size: 100%;
    text-align: left;
    line-height: 1;
}
```

Edit: This is how it looks currently.

[image: TABLE ACTUAL LOOKING]

Comment: Paragraph inside Anchor... Nice... It is like Bottle inside Water. :)

Comment: Perhaps the default margin/padding in a paragraph is the issue.

Comment: Also, that's a terrible way to make menus

Comment: Do you think you could replicate the problem on a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/).

Comment: Try with this <table cellpadding="0">

Comment: If they want that in a table I can do nothing. Thanks for the replies. I'll try to explain it to the customer.

Comment: @MiguelPérezAlonso It's been 10 mins, you could have at least posted a screenshot showing a red hand drawn circle of what's exactly happening. Also one person commented out saying the issue is with paragraph. So `margin: 0; padding: 0;` for the paragraph might fix. Did you read all the comments?

Comment: @Paulie_D Looks like this is a footer menu buddy. I guess the website audience is using IE 5 on Windows 95. :)

Comment: @MiguelPérezAlonso, could you post a screenshot of what you are trying to build? I'd be a lot easier to give you some answer :)

Comment: That's not a footer menu. It had to be a table with info but the customer change his mind in the very last moment. I don't know why they want that this way.

Comment: @MiguelPérezAlonso In your screenshot, I could see one part which has a top space. Is that what you are talking about? Can you create a http://jsbin.com to illustrate it?

Comment: I've found the error while I was doing the JSBin. It was a CSS rule that changes the padding top of absolutely all the elements inside the table so the rule affected to the anchor and the paragraph. Thanks for the help and sorry if I make you all waste your time.

Comment: @MiguelPérezAlonso Happy that you learnt something. So don't regret for that.